# How to prevent fade out on mouse hover of ajax response based div using jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to append an alert box in response of ajax which has fade in and fade out properties. The alert bar is working properly, currently below function is properly showing alert bar on ajax success and automatically hiding after 6000 delay `fadeOut(6000)`.

### JS

```
function delet(id){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'js.php',
        data:{del:'yes',id:id},
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(response){
            if(response.success){
                $(".top_nav").prepend('<div class="alert alert-success notification_bar fade col-md-3"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>Alert!</strong>'+response.success+'</div>');
            }
            if(response.error){
                $(".top_nav").prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger notification_bar fade col-md-3"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>Alert!</strong>'+response.error+'</div>');

            }   
            $(".alert").delay(1000).addClass("in").fadeOut(6000);

        }
    });

}
```

But I don't want to hide automatically if mouse hover on the alert bar, for task i'm trying below trick.

```
success: function(response){
     ...
     ...
     $(".alert").delay(1000).addClass("in"); // here i'm removing .fadeOut(6000)
}
```

After the `delet()` function i'm trying below code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".notification_bar").on({
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(1000);
        },
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
        }
    });  
});
```

I'm not sure this kind of trick should be work or not. Can anyone guide me where i'm wrong that i can fix my issue. I will appreciate if someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

The "trick" you try won't get your automatic `fadeOut` if the mouse is not hovered on the alert. Just add a condition on your fadeOut function based on weather the element has a certain class:

```
if(!$(".alert").hasClass("in")){
     $(".alert").delay(1000).addClass("in").fadeOut(6000);
}
```

and add a function to add/remove the `in` class when the mouse is out.

```
$(".alert").on("mouseenter", function(){
    $(this).addClass("in");
});
```

Comment: Second script should be outside the function ?